# In AWS IoT analytics, for the Service-managed store, which AWS database is used in the background and which AWS service is used to query the dataset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-analytics

In AWS IoT analytics, for the Service-managed store, which AWS database is used in the background to hold the data?

And when this data store is queried via the IoT analytics dataset, does it use the AWS Athena service in the background?

Answer (score 0):

WHen you create a query data set in IoT Analytics, it uses AWS Athena behind the scenes to query your data and generate results.

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotanalytics/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#quickstart-create-dataset step 5.